# Set password with Telegram TL

Tags: telegram

I'd like to enable Two-Step Verification for my telegram client and set a password for it.

I couldn't find any hint in official documents or any function for this purpose but I tried following functions anyway:

```
auth.recoverPassword#4ea56e92 code:string = auth.Authorization
auth.requestPasswordRecovery#d897bc66 = auth.PasswordRecovery
auth.checkPassword#0a63011e password_hash:bytes = auth.Authorization
auth.signUp#1b067634 phone_number:string phone_code_hash:string phone_code:string first_name:string last_name:string = auth.Authorization;
```

None of them have any related parameter neither return anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [this](https://tjhorner.com/tl-schema/) unofficial site, try this:

```
account.updatePasswordSettings#fa7c4b86 current_password_hash:bytes new_settings:account.PasswordInputSettings = Bool;
```